# Counting the occurrences of letters directly in a list of words with dictionaries

Tags: performance

I have problems in counting with a dictionary the occurrences of letters in a list of words of different length for each index of letters. The list is ordered from longest to shortest word. Like so:

```py
main_list = ['elephant','mouse','tiger','dog']
```

For index `0` the dictionary should be:
`{'e':1,'m':,'t':1,'d':1}`

For index `1`:
`{'l':1,'o':2,'i':1}`

For index `2`:
`{'e':1,'u':1,'g':2}`

and so on until the longest word is ended.

The output should be a list of dictionaries:

```py
main_list = [{'e':1,'m':1,'t':1,'d':1},{'l':1,'o':2,'i':1},{'e':1,'u':1,'g':2}...]
```

(also the shortest word should be included)

To solve the problem I created lists of letters for each index and then made a dictionary to count the occurrences of the letters for each list of letters, but I was wondering if there is a way to count directly in the list of words the occurrences of letters for each index.

Comment: Try this ```results = [Counter(tp) for tp in zip(*main_list) ]```

Comment: The requirement is not clear - do you want to count including short word?

Comment: Yes also the shortest, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use *collections* module Counter like this:

Notes: if you want to continue counting to include the shortest word - *dog,* after exhausting the *longest* one then you should use **zip_longest.**

```py
from collections import Counter

results = [Counter(tp) for tp in zip(*main_list) ]  # it ending with longest word

print(results)
# [Counter({'e': 1, 'm': 1, 't': 1, 'd': 1}), Counter({'o': 2, 'l': 1, 'i': 1}), Counter({'g': 2, 'e': 1, 'u': 1})]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main_list = ['elephant','mouse','tiger','dog']

from collections import Counter
from itertools import zip_longest

results = [Counter(filter(None,tp)) for tp in zip_longest(*main_list,fillvalue=None)]

for r in results:
    print(r)

# Counter({'e': 1, 'm': 1, 't': 1, 'd': 1})
# Counter({'o': 2, 'l': 1, 'i': 1})
# Counter({'g': 2, 'e': 1, 'u': 1})
# Counter({'p': 1, 's': 1, 'e': 1})
# Counter({'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'r': 1})
# Counter({'a': 1})
# Counter({'n': 1})
# Counter({'t': 1})
```

Use `zip_longest` for iterating until the longest element is processed. It requires a `fillvalue` which I set to `None`. I also filtered the elements of falsy values (such as this added `None`). I based it on @Daniel Hao's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import zip_longest
from pprint import pprint

main_list = ["elephant", "mouse", "tiger", "dog"]

pprint(
    [
        {k: v for k, v in Counter(t).items() if k}
        for t in zip_longest(*main_list, fillvalue=None)
    ]
)
```

output:

```
[{'d': 1, 'e': 1, 'm': 1, 't': 1},
 {'i': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 2},
 {'e': 1, 'g': 2, 'u': 1},
 {'e': 1, 'p': 1, 's': 1},
 {'e': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1},
 {'a': 1},
 {'n': 1},
 {'t': 1}]
```

Since you need to iterate according to the longest word, you need `zip_longest` instead of `zip`. Count the characters using `Counter` class and then filter out the keys that are `None`.